# need to migrate from Fuse ESB Enterprise 7.0.0.fuse-061 to jboss-fuse-6.2.0.redhat-133

Tags: jbossfuse

need to migrate from Fuse ESB Enterprise 7.0.0.fuse-061 to latest jboss-fuse-6.2.0.redhat-133.what are the main difference between these two versions?
what new features that are evolved in the latest jboss-fuse-6.2.0.redhat-133 that not exists in Fuse ESB Enterprise 7.0.0.fuse-061.can you please provide the links which gives us differences?

what are the camel,karaf ,cxf and activemq versions in these two versions?

jdk 1.6 can be used on former one and jdk1.7,jdk1.8 will be used in latest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the release notes here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2/html/Release_Notes/index.html.

Also checkout Jon Anstey's blog: http://janstey.blogspot.de/2015/06/jboss-fuse-62-is-out.html